# Can Dandelion defeat you?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In the sidequest 'The cabaret', Dandelion wants to fight you with fake swords so he can seduce a woman (to get money from her father).

During the fight, you can 1-2 shot Dandelion, but after you destroyed him, he seems crossed that you kicked his ass.

I took a few hits from him to sell the lie, and he would do about as much as if I would get punched. I could take maybe 20 hits from him to go down.

Question is: Does the quest go differently if I took the fall to Dandelion, or would I simply Game Over on it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can let Dandelion beat you up. After losing some hit points, a cutscene will play where Geralt will pretend to be defeated and Dandelion gets his glorious victory.

Comment: Clearing out all these comments since this argument has gotten pretty lengthy, and it's pretty clear that @Fennekin isn't going to change his mind. I will say, though, that downvoting an answer because of a single typo which has since been corrected borders on abuse of the downvote feature. Just try to keep that in mind when voting in the future.